# Can't center a percentage width box inside a percentage width box

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid container of 96% width.

I have a box inside this container which also has percentage width.

I can't get the box to center horizontally inside the wrapper. The usual `margin:0 auto;` isn't working - I guess because it has a percentage width.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <img class="scales"... />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
#wrapper {
    width:98%;
}

.box {
    width:40%;
}

.scales {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I bet you're just _thinking_ it isn't centered because the image isn't.

Comment: This is a great website that will clear up some confusion, you can use  position to help with the nesting of dynamic elements. http://learnlayout.com/position.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that your image does not look centered as it is likely smaller than the 40% of it's containing div. In any case, there is no reason for `margin:0 auto;` not to work. Solution to center the image:

```
.box {
    width:40%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jg4W5/)**

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    width:98%;
     background-color:#999;
}
.box {
    width:40%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.scales {
    width:100%;
}
```